# Using $$rAF in angular app

Tags: angularjs, requestanimationframe

I'm creating a directive that animates a sequence of images (allowing to play, stop, and step). In order to get the best performance, I would like to utilize requestAnimationFrame. I noticed that there is a requestAnimationFrame service in the angular source, prefixed with double dollar signs ($$rAF) which I presume indicates that it's not for public consumption. Why is this and what downsides are there to using this service as opposed to creating one myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this

It was introduced to replace `$timeout` for animations in the `$animate` service:

> use requestAnimationFrame instead of a timeout to issue a reflow

In the changelog for AngularJS 1.2.9

> what downsides are there to using this service as opposed to creating one myself?

- You have to provide a public API
- Any [issues in $$raf](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/search?q=raf&type=Issues) are included
- The documentation is lacking

**References**

- [AngularJS 1.2.9 Changelog: Features - $animate](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-53)
- [AngularJS requestAnimationFrame unit tests: rafSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/rafSpec.js)